# How can I insert a large space that disappears on line break?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website where I have a centered title containing the name and code of an airport above an image of that airport.

[image: Screenshot of website on a large screen]

I have the name and code of the airport separated by an em space:

```css
div.terminal-silhouette-container h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

div.terminal-silhouette-links {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

div.terminal-silhouette-preview {
 max-width: 500px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

img.terminal-silhouette-preview {
 border: 1px solid $color-border;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 terminal-silhouette-container">
  <h3>Orlando (International)&emsp;MCO</h3>
 <div class="terminal-silhouette-preview">
      <a href="files/terminal-silhouettes/png/MCO.png">
        <img class="img-responsive terminal-silhouette-preview" src="/assets/projects/terminal-silhouettes/MCO.png" alt="MCO" />
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="terminal-silhouette-links"><a href="files/terminal-silhouettes/png/MCO.png">png</a> &middot; <a href="files/terminal-silhouettes/svg/MCO.svg">svg</a></div>
</div>
```

This works exactly as I want on larger screens, but when I'm on a narrower mobile screen, the title wraps. Wrapping isn't a problem for me, but because of the em space, one of the lines ends up appearing off-center:

[image: Screenshot of website on a phone]

Is there a way in HTML or CSS to get the browser to treat the em space like a normal space – that is, ignore it (for centering text) if it's at the end of a line?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating your CSS for the H3 titles to prevent overflow and wrapping like this:

```
div.terminal-silhouette-container h3 {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Quantastical - should be `hidden`. Answer updated.

Comment: The above does prevent wrapping, but I actually do want it to wrap if necessary – I just don't want the em space making the text off center if it does wrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the name in a span and give it margin left of lets say 20 px  Then on smaller screens you can do do a media query to remove the margin.

```
span{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    span{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. It does work for this specific case. Thinking about it more, though, it's not just a problem on smaller screens (which your answer solves) – if I ever get an airport with an especially long name, I could end up with wrapping even on larger screens, and the same spacing issue with wrapped text.